# PHP convert large Decimal number to Hexadecimal

Tags: php, hex, decimal, bigdecimal, phpseclib

I am extracting information from a certificate using php and whilst the data is returned okay, there is one particular value "SerialNumber" which is being returned in what seems to be a different number format not sure what it is..

As an example, the actual format I am expecting to receive is:

> ‎58 ce a5 e3 63 51 b9 1f 49 e4 7a 20 ce ff 25 0f

However, what I am actually getting back is this:

> 118045041395046077749311747456482878735

Here is my php to perform the lookup:

```
$serial = $cert['tbsCertificate']['serialNumber'];
```

I have tried doing a few different conversions but none of them came back with the expected format.

Sample of a typical certificate serialnumber field..

[image]

VAR DUMP

```
    ["version"]=>
    string(2) "v3"
    ["serialNumber"]=>
    object(Math_BigInteger)#5 (6) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(39) "118045041395046077749311747456482878735"
      ["is_negative"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["generator"]=>
      string(7) "mt_rand"
      ["precision"]=>
      int(-1)
      ["bitmask"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["hex"]=>
      NULL
```

Comment: How are you extracting the information from the certificate in the first place?

Comment: Hi Barmer, i am using phpseclib.. sample here [link](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/decoder.php) , simply hit decode and expand the tree to get to SerialNumber

Comment: i also updated my post to add a screenshot to show you what a typical serialnumber looks like

Comment: You are getting back only numeric values but you need an alpha-numeric return. Have you tried string casting the result? Try `$serial = (string) $cert['tbsCertificate']['serialNumber'];` But this probably won't do anything seeing as we can't see the code which originally sets the values of `$cert['tbsCertificate']` and its subkeys, which is sure to be where the real problem lies I think.

Comment: yup, no difference. I even tried bin2hex() strval() and a few others but no joy

Comment: fair enough, so probably issue is with phpseclib?

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump($cert)`?

Comment: updated post with var_dump

Comment: @DrewT: No, the value is correctly processed into a `BigInteger` object, I added an answer.

Comment: @MadanSapkota: you probably misinterpreted the question. Your solution follows a really bad design pattern, as you are not using the functionality of an already present library, instead you reimplement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SerialNumber is a [`Math_BigInteger`](https://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger/docs/1.0.2/Math_BigInteger/Math_BigInteger.html) object as the `var_dump` shows.
Use the `toHex` method to retrieve the contained number in a hexadecimal format.
See reference on [PEAR website](https://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger/docs/1.0.2/Math_BigInteger/Math_BigInteger.html#methodtoHex).

```
$serial = $cert['tbsCertificate']['serialNumber'];
$valueInHex = $serial->toHex();
```

Note: *118045041395046077749311747456482878735* in decimal format equals to *58CEA5E36351B91F49E47A20CEFF250F* in hexadecimal format. You may easily check that with an online converter like [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html).

Comment: I have a question which is not related to mentioned question. I want to know, what is the name of these numbers: `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, ...` Do you know ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative solution to convert decimal number to hexadecimal format without using external libraries.

```
$dec = '118045041395046077749311747456482878735';
// init hex array
$hex = array();

while ($dec) {
    // get modulus // based on docs both params are string
    $modulus = bcmod($dec, '16');
    // convert to hex and prepend to array
    array_unshift($hex, dechex($modulus));
    // update decimal number
    $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $modulus), 16);
}

// array elements to string
echo implode('', $hex);
```

And the output of the code ... [**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/SVxM1F)

> 58cea5e36351b91f49e47a20ceff250f

You can also use string concatenation instead of array prepend. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: The OP already uses `phpseclib`, as was told in the comments. `Math_BigInteger` is used by `phpseclib`, therefore my solution does not use any further 3rd party library. Your solution follows a bad design pattern, a typical case of "reinventing the wheel": the `Math_BigInteger` class already contains the required functionality, yet you for some unknown reason deny to use it :)

Comment: @CMate, ```Math_BigInteger``` is not part of PHP core, so it is external library. You cannot simple call alternative code as "BAD" and down vote LOL. You are using something mean it is not always the greatest and best. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand the fact, that `Math_BigInteger` was already used in the question posted by user3436467? It seems you do not.
Your solution would fetch the decimal value from a `Math_BigInteger` object and use your custom function to transform it to hexadecimal, instead of using the already present `toHex` method. Please read the original question thoroughly! Your solution is bad!

Comment: A remark: I downvoted your answer, because you labelled it not as an alternative, but as a better replacement for this question, which I disputed. I won't revoke my downvote, as you edited your answer, then stated in your last comment here that I downvoted your so called alternative solution, which is not true. I also had to report to moderators one of your comments because you placed personal insults in it.